# How can a guest view the "Pending Review" Post?

Tags: posts, permalinks, post-status

1. When a user creates a new post it will have "pending" status. So I want the **visitor (guest - not logged user)** to be able to view "Pending" posts and vote it to "Publish" if enough "X Votes". Google bot can also crawl "Pending" Posts.
2. I want to use permalink for "Pending" Post.

How can I do this?

Please help me! Thanks all friends!

Comment: Not an answer (I'm not allowed to comment), but I'm wondering if you've ever figured this out? I'm also looking to allow visitors to see pending posts even though they don't necessarily have the proper credentials. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is with this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/

OF course you can dig into it's source code to try to implement the core functionality if you prefer, but I use that plugin on several active sites with success.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying "Pending" post to the users you can add "post_status" parameter to `get_post()` or `wp_query` function like

post_status (string / array) - use post status. Retrieves posts by Post Status. Default value is 'publish', but if the user is logged in, 'private' is added. And if the query is run in an admin context (administration area or AJAX call), protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are 'future', 'draft' and 'pending'.

```
'publish' - a published post or page.

'pending' - post is pending review.

'draft' - a post in draft status.

'auto-draft' - a newly created post, with no content.

'future' - a post to publish in the future.

'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in.

'inherit' - a revision. see get_children.

'trash' - post is in trashbin (available with Version 2.9).

'any' - retrieves any status except those from post types with 'exclude_from_search' set to true.
```

Or you can check the wordpress codex for other help.

Comment: I know it, but I want to visitor (guest - not logged user) and google-bot can view "Pending Review" Post. Thank you, friend!

Comment: @user31368, you will have to use http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query or http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts in order to use the method described by Zen. If you don't understand how to modify the loop or filter posts, please research those in the Codex. Otherwise you will need to hire help.

Comment: I think Wordpress is have a function in the core to exclude the visitor can view the pending post. So we need to know about that funtion. :(